# Add mysql data to listbox in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, listbox

I need to make VB take information from my MySQL Database and place it in a list box. So please could you help me out. I can't seem to understand how to insert it into a list box.

Comment: At wich point are you having problems?

Comment: I have no idea on how to bring in the data!

Comment: post us the code, that you have tried.!

Comment: I haven't tried any because i don't understand what is going on. I am trying to learn as well so an explanation would be nice along with a code. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code will help you to get an idea about what you are looking for.

```
Private sub FillListBox

    Dim stringConn As String
    Dim stringCmd As String
    Dim myConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As MySqlCommand

    'Frame your query here.
    stringCmd = "SELECT yourData FROM yourTable"

    'Frame your connection string here.
    stringConn = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=DBName;UID=root;PASSWORD=;"

    'Get your connection here.
    myConn = New MySqlConnection(stringConn)

    'Get a command by using your connection and query.
    myCmd = New MySqlCommand(stringCmd, myConn)

    'Open the connection.
    myConn.Open()

    'create a reader to store the datum which will be returned from the DB
    Dim myReader As MySqlDataReader

    'Execute your query using .ExecuteReader()
    myReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader()

    'Reset your List box here.
    ListBox1.items.clear()

    While (myReader.Read())
            'Add the items from db one by one into the list box.
        ListBox1.items.add(myReader.GetString(1))
    End While

    'Close the reader and the connection.
    myReader.Close()
    myConn.Close()

End Sub
```